# dicts and nested dicts python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

Attempting to understand dicts in a somewhat simple way I believe, but am thoroughly confused. When I run the code below, it works fine to populate dict and count the occurrences of a word. Output is as such: `{'gerry': 2, 'babona': 1, 'cheese': 1, 'cherry': 1}`

```
dict = {}

a = ['gerry', 'babona', 'cheese', 'gerry', 'cherry']
b = ['O' ,'O', 'T', 'T', 'T']

for (i,j) in zip(a,b):

  if i not in dict:
    dict[i] = 1
  else:
    dict[i] += 1
```

However, if I try to run the following code, there is a `KeyError: 'gerry'`, beginning with the first value in the list, but I cannot make sense of why. Any help on this greatly appreciated!

```
dict = {}

a = ['gerry', 'babona', 'cheese', 'gerry', 'cherry']
b = ['O' ,'O', 'T', 'T', 'T']

for (i,j) in zip(a,b):

  if i not in dict:
    dict[i][j] = 1
  else:
    dict[i][j] += 1
```

Comment: Exactly what do you want your code to do? / what is the desired output?

Comment: `dict[i][j] = 1` why are you doing this?

Answer (score 3):

The first example can be simpler

```
from collections import Counter

a = ['gerry', 'babona', 'cheese', 'gerry', 'cherry']

data = Counter(a)
```

For second

```
from collections import defaultdict


a = ['gerry', 'babona', 'cheese', 'gerry', 'cherry']
b = ['O', 'O', 'T', 'T', 'T']

data = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))

for (i, j) in zip(a, b):
    data[i][j] += 1
```

btw don't use reserved name for your variable eg `dict`

Answer (score 2):

When the program gets to: `dict[i][j] = 1` it has to execute: `dict[i]` first, which is exactly what you were trying to avoid when you wrote the first snippet.

You will have to do multi-stage tests to get this to work.

You can get it to work like this, but there are simpler ways:

```py
dct = {}

a = ['gerry', 'babona', 'cheese', 'gerry', 'cherry']
b = ['O' ,'O', 'T', 'T', 'T']

for (i,j) in zip(a,b):
  if i not in dct:
    dct[i] = {}
    dct[i][j] = 1
  else:
    di = dct[i]
    if j not in di:
        di[j] = 0
    dct[i][j] += 1
print(dct)
```

Output:

```
{'gerry': {'O': 1, 'T': 1}, 'babona': {'O': 1}, 'cheese': {'T': 1}, 'cherry': {'T': 1}}
```

Comment: We may have to agree to disagree ;-)  This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66186848) from [elektruver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11234907/elektruver) is simpler.

Comment: awesone! This is the output form I was looking for! Thank you so much. I wanted to do this without importing any libraries as well, works on both levels for me

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
a = ['gerry', 'babona', 'cheese', 'gerry', 'cherry']
b = ['O' ,'O', 'T', 'T', 'T']
print(Counter(a))
Counter({'gerry': 2, 'babona': 1, 'cheese': 1, 'cherry': 1})
```

for the 2nd case you can use `groupby`

```
dct = dict((key, tuple(v for (k, v) in pairs)) 
           for (key, pairs) in groupby(sorted(zip(a,b)), lambda pair: pair[0]))
{k:Counter(v) for k,v in dct.items()}
{'babona': Counter({'O': 1}), 'cheese': Counter({'T': 1}),'cherry': Counter({'T': 1}), 'gerry': Counter({'O': 1, 'T': 1})}
```